# Where can I get windows/linux binaries for Z3opt

Tags: z3, z3py

The link mentioned in the online tutorial doesn't contain any link to opt branch:

```
http://z3.codeplex.com/
```

and also there isn't any page under download section... Is it possible to get the binaries for windows/linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's on the "Source" page where you can select the branch that you would like to see. Once you have git-cloned the whole repository, you can also select the unstable branch on the command line, or whatever your preferred git client is.

At the moment we don't build binaries that contain the opt branch, the binaries in the Download section are master releases, and if you select "planned" in the panel on the right you can get the unstable binaries.

Codeplex is currently undergoing serious maintenance work, so you might have to try multiple times before you get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is here https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/branches select opt branch.